# Intent is not working in cardview in my application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-service

The Intent is not working in the cardview. Toast is working but Intent is not working in this how can i work with this please help to do this

This is the error occure in logcats
    E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc

I this I cant find the way to intent ,It make me totally confused and blank,Why? This happen to me like this,is any one know this please help me friends i got too much of worried in this on place pleace 
my Mainactivity

```
package com.onebook.msv;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private GridLayout gridLayout;
    private CardView card1,card2,card3,card4,card5;
    private TextView c1t1,c1t2,c2t1,c2t2,c3t1,c3t2,c4t1,c4t2,c5t1,c5t2;
    Session_Manager sm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            gridLayout=(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
            setsingleevent(gridLayout);




       /* Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);*/
       /* fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer,  R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




    }

    private void setsingleevent(GridLayout gridLayout){




        for (int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){

            CardView cardView=(CardView)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
            final int finalI=i;

            if (i==0) {
                c1t2=gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.card1txtview2);
                c1t2.setText("1958 ");

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                      Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Listapproval.class);
                      startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });
            }

            if (i==1) {
                c2t2=gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.card2txtview2);
                c2t2.setText("1958 ");

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is in the postion" + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
            }

            if (i==2) {
                c3t2=gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.card3txtview2);
                c3t2.setText("1958 ");

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is in the postion" + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
            }

            if (i==3) {
                c4t2=gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.card4txtview2);
                c4t2.setText("195 ");

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is in the postion" + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
            }

            if (i==4) {
                c5t2=gridLayout.findViewById(R.id.card5txtview2);
                c5t2.setText("195 ");

                cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is in the postion" + finalI, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
            }




        }








        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://squaredotssolutions.com/demo/chit/api/total_details.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
          /*  String inputuserid = userid.getText().toString();
            String inputPassword = password.getText().toString();*/


            String data = "status=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();


            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            String response = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            progressDialog.cancel();

            JSONObject response_data = new JSONObject(response);
            if (response_data.getString("status").equals("true")) {
               /* sm.setLoginmobile(inputuserid);
                sm.setLoginpassword(inputPassword);*/
                // based on the wanted response we need to change this
              /*  sm.settotalcustomers(response_data.getJSONObject("customer").getString("totalCustomers"));
                sm.settotalcollections(response_data.getJSONObject("collection").getString("totalCollection"));
                sm.settotalavailablevalus(response_data.getJSONObject("amt").getString("totalCollection"));
                sm.settotalamount(response_data.getString("message"));
                sm.setstatus (response_data.getString("status"));
*/
                String customer=response_data.getJSONObject("customer").getString("totalCustomers");
                // String collection=response_data.getJSONObject("collection").getString("totalCollection");
                String available=response_data.getJSONObject("amt").getString("totalAmount");

                c1t2.setText(customer);
                c2t2.setText("258");
                c3t2.setText(available);
                c4t2.setText("125");
                c5t2.setText("available");

                // sm.setAddress(response_data.getJSONObject("data").getString("address"));
                sm.setFirstname(response_data.getJSONObject("data").getString("feb_username"));
                sm.setEmail(response_data.getJSONObject("data").getString("email"));
                sm.setSymbol(response_data.getJSONObject("data").getString("symbol"));
                sm.setdialcode(response_data.getJSONObject("data").getString("dial_code"));

                //intend for next page
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (response_data.getString("status").equals("2")) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("No Datas Available")
                        .setCancelable(false).setIcon(R.drawable.sorry).setTitle("Login Status")
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"somthing went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tools) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

my recycleview class

```
    package com.onebook.msv;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Listapproval extends AppCompatActivity {
    Session_Manager sm;
    List<ListApprovalMode> listApprovalModeslist;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listtoapprove);

       listApprovalModeslist=new ArrayList<ListApprovalMode>();

        getdata();

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclewlistview);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         adapter = new Adapterlist(getApplicationContext(),listApprovalModeslist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public void getdata(){

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Listapproval.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://squaredotssolutions.com/demo/chit/api/total_details.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
          /*  String inputuserid = userid.getText().toString();
            String inputPassword = password.getText().toString();*/


            String data = "status=" + URLEncoder.encode("1", "UTF-8")+ "&category_id=" + URLEncoder.encode("5", "UTF-8");;

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();


            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            String response = "";

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
            progressDialog.cancel();

            JSONObject response_data = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray array=response_data.getJSONArray("details");
            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {
                JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                String sno = " ";
                String customer_id = " ";
                String customer_name =  " ";
                String account_no =  " ";
                String category_id =  " ";
                String category =  " ";
                String partner_id =  " ";
                String partner_name =  " ";
                String amount =  " ";
                String payin_id =  " ";
                String payin =  " ";
                String balance =  " ";


                if(ob.getString("status").equals("1")) {

                    sno = ob.getString("sno");
                    customer_id = ob.getString("customer_id");
                    customer_name = ob.getString("customer_name");
                    account_no = ob.getString("account_no");
                    category_id = ob.getString("category_id");
                    category = ob.getString("category");
                    partner_id = ob.getString("partner_id");
                    partner_name = ob.getString("partner_name");
                    amount = ob.getString("amount");
                    payin_id = ob.getString("payin_id");
                    payin = ob.getString("payin");
                    balance = ob.getString("balance");
                    String status = ob.getString("status");
                }
                listApprovalModeslist.add(0,new ListApprovalMode(sno,customer_id,customer_name,account_no,category_id,category,partner_id,partner_name,amount,payin_id,payin,balance));
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

my adapter

```
package com.onebook.msv;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

class Adapterlist extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapterlist.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ListApprovalMode> listApprovalModeslist;

    public Adapterlist(Context applicationContext, List<ListApprovalMode> listApprovalModes) {
        this.context=applicationContext;
        this.listApprovalModeslist=listApprovalModes;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycleview_item, parent, false);


        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ListApprovalMode listApprovalMode=listApprovalModeslist.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(listApprovalMode.getCustomer_name());
        holder.linid.setText(listApprovalMode.getCustomer_id());
        holder.totalamount.setText(listApprovalMode.getAmount());
        holder.payin.setText(listApprovalMode.getPayin());
        holder.balance.setText((listApprovalMode.getBalance()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listApprovalModeslist.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView name,linid,totalamount,payin,balance;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            linid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            totalamount=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            payin=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            balance=itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }

}
```

this my mode

```
package com.onebook.msv;

public class ListApprovalMode {

    String sno, customer_id,  customer_name,  account_no,  category_id,  category,  partner_id,  partner_name,  amount,  payin_id, payin, balance;
    public ListApprovalMode(String sno, String customer_id, String customer_name, String account_no, String category_id, String category, String partner_id, String partner_name, String amount, String payin_id, String payin, String balance) {

        this.sno=sno;
        this.customer_id=customer_id;
        this.customer_name=customer_name;
        this.account_no=account_no;
        this.category_id=category_id;
        this.category=category;
        this.partner_id=partner_id;
        this.partner_name=partner_name;
        this.amount=amount;
        this.payin_id=payin_id;
        this.payin=payin;
        this.balance=balance;
    }

 public String getSno(){return sno;}
 public void setSno(String sno){this.sno=sno;};
    public String getCustomer_id(){return customer_id;}
    public void setCustomer_id(String customer_id){this.customer_id=customer_id;}
    public String getCustomer_name(){return customer_name;}
    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name){this.customer_name=customer_name;}
    public String getAccount_no(){return getAccount_no();}
    public void setAccount_no(String account_no){this.account_no=account_no;}
    public String getCategory_id(){return category_id;}
    public void setCategory_id(String category_id){this.category_id=category_id;}
    public String getCategory(){return category;}
    public void setCategory(String category){this.category=category;}
    public String getPartner_id(){return partner_id;}
    public void setPartner_id(String partner_id){this.partner_id=partner_id;}
    public String getPartner_name(){return partner_name;}
    public void setPartner_name(String partner_name){this.partner_name=partner_name;};
    public String getAmount(){return amount;}
    public void setAmount(String amount){this.amount=amount;};
    public String getPayin_id(){return payin_id;}
    public void setPayin_id(String payin_id){this.payin_id=payin_id;};
    public String getPayin(){return payin;}
    public void setPayin(String payin){this.payin=payin;};
    public String getBalance(){return balance;}
    public void setBalance(String balance){this.balance=balance;};

}
```

I have been stuck here for a long time please any one help me to solve this please .

Comment: **`adapter = new Adapterlist(getApplicationContext(),listApprovalModeslist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);`** Cut this code from `onCreate()` and paste after `listApprovalModeslist.add();` I think your code is perfect but your flow is little bit confusing.

Comment: i done that before but it's not working. recycleview screen is totally blank in my application

Comment: After `setContentView` bind your `recyclerview` then call `getdata();` method and then bind your data.

Comment: i do that also but when debugging i can't go to the listapproval(recycleview) page ? why?....when i debug ..the card on click it go to the View.class  ,Drawable background = null; ....why

Comment: add adapter.notifuDatasetChanged() at the end of getData() and put getData() after set adapter.

Comment: Is that works for you friend ?..... it still a blank page for me . it"s not work ..

Comment: E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc ... this is the error occure in logcat

Comment: You need to post the entire error message with stack trce. The "E/HAL" message you have posted is not an error. You should probably remove any filtering of the logcat because you are probably missing the real cause of your problem. Do not post the error and stacktrace as a comment, please edit your question and post the information in the question.

Comment: Also, `Intent` is spelled with a "T" at the end, not a "D".